# C++ virtual function resolution issue

Tags: c++, function, virtual

The program throws an error at this function call resolution:

```
for(vector<Catalog*>::iterator i=m_subDeptList.begin(); i!=m_subDeptList.end();  ++i)
         (*i)->displayDiscription();
```

The Error:

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘void Department::displayDiscription()’:
test.cpp:73:14: error: ‘class Catalog’ has no member named ‘displayDiscription’
    (*i)->displayDiscription();
```

But there are no issues with the following call resolutions:

```
for(vector<Product*>::iterator i=m_products.begin(); i!=m_products.end();  ++i)
        (*i)->displayDiscription();
for(vector<Catalog*>::iterator i=m_subDeptList.begin() ; i!=m_subDeptList.end();  ++i)
        (*i)->addDiscount(discount);
for(vector<Product*>::iterator  i=m_products.begin(); i!=m_products.end();  ++i)
        (*i)->addDiscount(discount);
```

Can anybody explain this?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Catalog
{
    string m_name;
public:
    Catalog(const string &name):m_name(name){}
    //virtual ~Catalog(){}
    const string& getName()
    {
        return m_name;
    }

    virtual bool addDiscount(unsigned int discount)=0;
    virtual void displayDescription()=0;      
};
class Product:public Catalog
{
    unsigned short m_discount; // discount in %
    long double m_price;
public:
    Product(const string& productName, const long double &price):Catalog(productName),m_price(price){}
    void displayDiscription()
    {
        cout<<getName()<<"price: "<<getPrice()<<endl;
    }    
    bool addDiscount(const unsigned int discount)
    {
        if( discount > 100 || discount < 0)
            return false;
        m_discount+=discount;
        return true;
    }
    long double getPrice()
    {
        return m_price;
    }

};
class Department:public Catalog
{
    vector<Product*> m_products;
    vector<Catalog*> m_subDeptList;
    unsigned int discountApplied;
public:
    Department(const string &name):Catalog(name){}

    bool addDiscount(unsigned int discount) // add discount to all products in this dept/subDept
    {
        if( discount > 100 || discount < 0)
            return false;

        for(vector<Catalog*>::iterator i=m_subDeptList.begin() ; i!=m_subDeptList.end();  ++i)
            (*i)->addDiscount(discount);
        for(vector<Product*>::iterator  i=m_products.begin(); i!=m_products.end();  ++i)
            (*i)->addDiscount(discount);
        discountApplied+=discount;
        return true;
    }    

    void displayDiscription()
    {

        cout<<getName()<<endl;

        if(!m_subDeptList.empty() )
        for(vector<Catalog*>::iterator i=m_subDeptList.begin(); i!=m_subDeptList.end();  ++i)
             (*i)->displayDiscription();

        if(!m_products.empty() )
            for(vector<Product*>::iterator i=m_products.begin(); i!=m_products.end();  ++i)
            (*i)->displayDiscription();

        return;

    }  
/*
    void addProduct(Product* pProduct)
    {
        m_products.push_back(pProduct);

    }
    void addDepartment(Catalog* pDepartment)
    {
        m_subDeptList.push_back(pDepartment);

    }
*/
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
/*    
    Department megaStoreCatalog("catalog");
    Department stationary("Stationary");
    Product pen("pen", 5);
    stationary.addProduct(&pen);
    Department stationaryLiquid("Stationary-Liquid");
    Product ink("Bril",30);
    stationaryLiquid.addProduct(&ink);
    megaStoreCatalog.addDepartment(&stationary);
    stationary.addDepartment(&stationaryLiquid);

    megaStoreCatalog.addDiscount(10);

  */  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: I assume you're aware that 'displayDiscription' is not implemented in 'Catalog' or 'Product'? I'd say you're attempting to call a pure virtual.

Comment: Does your Catalog class need to be constructed directly? Meaning is it an actual object or is it a concept that other classes build off of? Another words is Catalog abstract?

Comment: ajshort,  sorry I forgot to add the error. the Error is added now

Comment: Francis Cugler,  I'm constructing Product and Department and storing them as a pointer to Catalog.

Comment: Steve, displayDiscription is implemented in Product and Department. So I'm not calling the pure virtual function Catalog::displayDiscription

Comment: Check my answer; I was in the process of writing it while someone down voted it; I had to edit to copy and paste from your code displayed in your question.

Comment: I asked because if you are not going to ever construct a Catalog object directly and only construct objects that are derived from Catalog then you should move the Catalog constructor to the protected section of its class. This way no outside class except for friends can call its constructor. All derived class will have access if it is in the protected section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can not resolve because your two derived classes methods are not found in the base class signature of that pure virtual function declaration. Your problem is not an implementation problem it is a spelling error.

Look at your spelling in both the Base and Derived classes; you spell one as `discription` and the other as `description`. Also you have one of the pure virtual methods with a `const` where it is not defined that way in the base class. Another thing is your constructor only has 1 parameter so you should be declaring that constructor with the `explicit` keyword before its name. You should not use the default constructor in the base even if it is empty or doesn't do anything and declare it as virtual.

In your Base Class

> virtual void displayDescription()=0;

In your Derived Classes

```
void displayDiscription()
{
    cout<<getName()<<"price: "<<getPrice()<<endl;
}
```

&

```
void displayDiscription()
{

    cout<<getName()<<endl;

    if(!m_subDeptList.empty() )
    for(vector<Catalog*>::iterator i=m_subDeptList.begin(); i!=m_subDeptList.end();  ++i)
         (*i)->displayDiscription();

    if(!m_products.empty() )
        for(vector<Product*>::iterator i=m_products.begin(); i!=m_products.end();  ++i)
        (*i)->displayDiscription();

    return;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just add `const` in `addDiscount`. It changes the function signature.

You should be using the C++11 [`override` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override).

Comment: I modified the signature of the function addDiscount as bool addDiscount(const unsigned int discount) in all the 3 classes. Still I'm getting the same error.